# Windows XP cannot connect to samba share (linux server 20.04)

Tags: networking, server, password, samba, file-sharing

i am new to linux and samba server.

i try to setup samba server.
my windows 7 and windows 10 can connect perfectly to samba server.

the problem is windows XP cannot connect nor browse the samba server, it said :
"windows cannot find "\server". Check the spelling and try again....."

and this is my conf setting :

```
[global]
passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
unix password sync = yes
winbind trusted domains only = yes
username map = /etc/samba/smbusers
os level = 20
client min protocol = NT1
encrypt passwords = yes
map to guest = bad user
workgroup = WORKGROUP
netbios name = server
security = user
panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
guest ok = yes
lanman auth = yes
log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
max log size = 1000
ntlm auth = yes
passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
obey pam restrictions = yes
logging = file
winbind use default domain = yes
server string = 
usershare allow guests = yes
auto services = global
server role = standalone server
pam password change = yes
```

[image]

please help

Comment: There were changes because of WannaCry and windows being impacted by it... Was your XP patched for that (XP was EOL and thus patches weren't generally applied) and used an older SaMBa version than is used today. Is your XP using a modern `vers=` option?  Your issue is likely with the XP machine and thus off-topic here.

Comment: thanks for the clue, i will try to search for the patch.
is it KB4012598 patch if i am not wrong ?

Comment: Does this reference help in any way? https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently

Comment: @User24601 i will check that out, thanks
will update if works

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have 'client min protocol = NT1' set, there is another similar setting 'server min protocol' which from Samba 4.11.0 is set to SMBv2. Your XP is probably only using SMBv1, so it will not be able to see or connect to your Samba server.

So you have to edit the `[global]` section in the `/etc/samba/smb.conf` and add the `server min protocol = NT1` option here. Then restart the Samba service.

Comment: And just anecdotally, setting server min protocol to NT1 and restarting smbd and nmbd may not be enough. You may need to reboot the server to reinitalte the master browser process.

Comment: @Morbius1 i will try your suggestion, thanks for the clue

Comment: thanks all @Morbius1@rowland Penny, 
i set my server from `client min protocol = NT1` to `server min protocol = NT1`.
restart samba server and boom everything work perfectly on windows XP :))

Comment: For the search engines . . . 

`C:\>net view \\myserver`

resulted in "error 71":

`System error 71 has occurred.

No more connections can be made to this remote computer at this time because there are already as many connections as the computer can accept.`

Adding `server min protocol = NT1` as above fixed that.  Thanks!

Comment: `sudo systemctl restart smbd` to restart samba in Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Answer (score 11):

With an old Windows XP and Samba 4.9.5 on a Debian 10

```
server min protocol = NT1

lanman auth = yes

ntlm auth = yes
```

Comment: Adding `server min protocol = NT1` was not enough in my case. I also needed to add `lanman auth =yes` and `ntlm auth = yes` as explained in this answer. And it was enough to just restart Samba... in my case using the command: `systemctl restart samba` Thank you.

Comment: these three keys did it for my environment: samba server 4.13 (debian) and win2003

Comment: Don't use `server max protocol = NT1`  , use `server min protocol = NT1`  instead. `server max protocol = NT1` will prevent Windows 7 and above to access samba share.  So the complete commands would be `server min protocol = NT1`   `lanman auth = yes`  `ntlm auth = yes`

Comment: Just to confirm this configuration was exactly what I needed to enable Windows XP KVM VM to see a SAMBA daemon on my LAN. In my case, I could not use SAMBA server name but IP address worked fine. Interestingly, once a share had been mapped to a drive letter in Windows it resolved the IP address to the correct name.

Comment: `sudo systemctl restart smbd` to restart samba in Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS